# Sentry and Log4j version not getting upgraded on remote server

Tags: java, ubuntu, log4j, sentry

I have one remote test server, I want to upgrade the Sentry and Log4j to the latest version. I built my java project and on my local machine both Sentry and Log4j where now latest. But, when I upload the jar file to test server(remote server) and run the service it still shows the old version.
The jar is having the latest version of Sentry and Log4j.
Can anyone help me know why I am not able to upgrade these tools on my remote server.
Below is the latest version showing in the jar -
[image]

Comment: If the JAR you build has the latest version of these libraries, but when you run upload it on the test server it has old versions it means that you must be looking in wrong places or run wrong JAR on your test server. 

BTW - you can upgrade Log4j independently from Sentry SDK.